# Merging dataframes resulting in erratic result

Tags: python, pandas

I am merging 2 dataframes. insp_all(left) is 12 104 x 51 and alps_df(right) has 51 830 x 10.  Now I am merging left and the resulting dataframe has 1 419 140 rows and 61 columns.

I am not sure why this is happening. What is the proper syntax?

```
insp_all_final = insp_all.merge(alps_df, how='left', left_on='DRIVER_LICENSE', right_on='DRVR_LIC_NBR')
```

Comment: There is problem with duplicates in `DRIVER_LICENSE` or(and) `DRVR_LIC_NBR` columns.

Comment: how to counter that, VLOOKUP in excel works good here, i need an exact alternative of VLOOKUP here. I need exact 12104 rows in resulting dataframe. I have removed duplicates in the other dataframe and then also getting 12446 rows.

Comment: Hmmmm, If no duplicate value it should work - check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44484550/2901002)

Comment: @jezrael does not mean duplicates across entire row but multiple instances of same driver license value within same dataset. Can there be more than one driver license in each table regardless of other content? If so, joins will merge to *every* match. Describe or better show some data. This is a classic problem of SQL joins between one-to-many or many-to-many related tables.

Comment: I cannot remove duplicates from my first data frame, that's the way it is supposed to be, Should I try using map instead of regular merge, will that give me desired result of 12104 rows? Please help...!!!

Comment: @Parfrait - you are bang on, there are multiple instances of same driver license with different values across variables but the lookup can be only on driver license. Kindly help. Excel works lot better in this regard.

Comment: without seeing the data i guess this is the problem: the table alps_df contains duplicate entries for DRIVER_LICENSE. Excel Vlookup will just go through the table and come back with the first match it finds. If you want to replicate this in pandas, you could simply do `alps_df = alps_df.drop_duplicates(['DRIVER_LICENSE'])` , thus removing the 'duplicate' records for DRIVER LICENSE entries and only keeping the first occurrence, but is this really what you want? Maybe there is a reason there are multiple entries?

Comment: @Bartdur - that was what I am referring to in my last comment. I have multiple instances of driver licenses in "insp_all" which I need to keep and I have dropped duplicates from "alps_df". But still because of the duplicates in "insp_all", I am getting more rows than my parent dataframe (imsp_all) after merging, which I do not want