# Lookup matched value from one dataframe and send to a different dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes:

```
df1
Name     Age     State     Postcode     AveAge_State_PC
John      40       PA        1000              35
Janet     40       LV        1050              30
Jake      30       PA        1000              35
Jess      20       LV        1050              30

df2
State        Postcode        AveAge_State_PC
PA             1000               ???
LV             1050               ???
```

How do I get the values into the 2nd table? They should all be the same so happy to take the first value that appears.

I have tried:

```
df2 = df2.merge(df1[['State', 'Postcode', 'AveAge_State_PC']], how = 'left',
                left_on = ['State', 'Postcode'], right_on = ['State', 'Postcode']).drop(columns= ['State', 'Postcode'])
```

but getting an

> ValueError: You are trying to merge on int64 and object columns.

**Edit**
Im also getting duplicate rows when merging rather than just keeping the same number of rows in `df2`

I assume because there are multiple same values in `df1`? any help would be much appreciated! thanks!

Comment: Convert `df1['Postcode'] = df1['Postcode'].astype(str)` or `df2['Postcode'] = df2['Postcode'].astype(int)` for same types

Comment: thanks! foxed the error issue but not im getting duplicate rows in `df2` (have made an edit to post

Comment: You are right, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44484520/merge-two-dataframes-without-repeats-pandas/44484550#44484550)